# Until when will Python 2.5 be supported?

Tags: python, python-2.5

Apparently Python only supports 2 minor versions (like 2.X), so that would mean Python 2.5 would get phased out when Python 2.7 comes out (in June 2010?)

Is this correct? [PEP 356 -- Python 2.5 Release Schedule](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0356/) doesn't give much answers to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.5 will continue to get security updates until September 2011.  See [this message](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-August/091387.html) by Martin v. Löwis, the Python 2.5 release manager.